# How to get ~/foo from /home/user1/foo?

Tags: linux, bash, path, home-directory

The Bash prompt supports the `\w` escape sequence, documented as

```
\w     the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated
       with a tilde (uses the value of the PROMPT_DIRTRIM variable)
```

Is there any way to get a similar abbreviation for an arbitrary string? That is, is there a general command that does something like the following, provided that HOME=/home/user1

```
/home/user1         → ~
/home/user1/a/1     → ~/a/1
/home/user2/b/2     → ~user2/b/2
/root               → ~root
```

Sure, I could try something ugly with sed, but that is unlikely to give me the result I want in any case. :-)

The movitation behind this is that I would like to keep the titles in the tabs of my terminals as short as possible, hence abbreviate working directories where possible.

**UPDATE:** As there doesn’t appear to be a satisfactory solution easily available, and I would like to keep things sufficiently fast, I now went with a simple

```
pwd | sed -e "s|/root|~root|" -e "s|/home/user1|~|
```

and something similar for root. As I am the only user on the machine, this currently works more or less. I will keep the question open in case someone comes up with `magical-tool-that-solves-all-problems` (ideally not written in elisp…).

Comment: “Make everything as simple as possible, but not simpler.” — Albert Einstein.  `s|/home/user1|~|` will change `/home/user17` to `~7`.

Answer (score 2):

For your own home directory, use **`dir="${PWD/#$HOME/~}"`**.

To just strip `/home/` as glenn suggests, also use `dir="${dir/#\/home\//~}"`.

---

Converting other users' homedirs is much more complicated, since you have to list *all* users every time.

- You can't even stop on the first match, since the few first accounts have a homedir of `/` which will always match. Instead, it is needed to check the *longest* prefix, which isn't simple.
- I often work with servers configured to read user accounts from LDAP, which takes a whole second to list all accounts; meanwhile, Active Directory wouldn't even allow to see the entire list.

Comment: If you want to assume that "regular" users have home directory beginning with "/home/", then `case "$PWD/" in ($HOME/*) dir="${PWD/#$HOME/~}" ;; (/home/*) dir="~${PWD:6}" ;; (*) dir="$PWD" ;; esac; echo "$dir"`

Comment: @grawity: Yes, I can see that it is somewhat more difficult to get back than forth, but I hope dies last. @Glenn: This already fails for `/root`. I shall go with a hand-written list instead, but thank you very much for your interest! :)

Answer (score 2):

For current user, and a string stored in a variable called `DIR`, this will work: `${DIR/~/\~}`

It replaces the expansion of `~`, which is either the value of the `$HOME` variable or the current user's home directory, with a literal `~`.